# Findif Peak value Coordinates in Mathematica MMA9.0

Tags: detection

I am stuck with little problem in MMA9.0.

I have obtain the curve, like I have detected a "peak" in the noisy observations. But, I am not aware how to find the {x,y} coordinates of this peak.

```
   Could someone please help me in this regard.
```

Thanks and Regards,

Sanjay Kumar.